# Get user id and name from comment on Fan Page Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since Facebook API update to v2.11, I cannot get User Id and Name from comments on FanPage Wall Post. Anyone can help/explain?

Usually I used this :
https://graph.facebook.com/[POST_ID_PAGE]/comments?order=reverse_chronological&access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]

```
And the result just like :
{
"data": [
{
"created_time": values_date_TMZ,
"from": {
"name": USER_NAME,
"id": USER_ID
},
"message": THE_COMMENT,
"id": THE_COMMENT_ID
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Page Token now, to get user names - check out the changelog:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi

I assume you are using an App Token at the moment.

Edit: Of course it has to be a Page Token of the Page with the comment. And of course you need to manage the Page - else you would not even get a Page Token.

Comment: Already get Page Token, create using Access Token Tools, then using my own Facebook Apps. But still no luck.

Comment: It needs to be a page access token for the page that the post is on.

Comment: what CBroe said. should be obvious, but i added it in my answer.